# really could use some assistance with variables declarations for my assignment

Tags: variables, textarea

ok here is what i got from you can you check if this is right i cant edit to much of it from what the book says so it has to stay somewhat in this format im guessing..hope you can help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
/* ]]> */

document.getElementById( news ) .innerHTML='newsItem1';

var newsItem1 = "L'AQUILA, ITALY (AP) - L'Aquila's chief prosecutor announced an investigation into allegations of shoddy construcation as workers continued to scour the rubble for people still missing after a devastating earthquake five days ago. http://in.reuters.com/article/idUSWBT01103020090411;

var newsItem2 = "WASHINGTON (Reuters) - President Barack Obama said on Friday the recession-hit US ecomony was showing 'glimmers of hope' despite remaining under strain and promised further steps in coming weeks to tackle the finicial crisis. http://in.reuters.com/article/idUSWBT01103020090411";

var newsItem3 = "(eWeek.com) - Apple is close to hitting 1 billion downloads from its App Store and plans on prize giveaway for whoever downloads the billionth application that includes a MacBook Pro and an iPod Touch. http://www.eweek.com/c/a/application-development/eweek-newsbreak-april-13-2009/";

var newsItem4 = "ALTANTA (AP) - Chipper Jones drove in two runs, including a tiebreaking single, and the Atlanta Braves beat Washington 8-5 on Sunday to hand the Nationals their sixth straight loss to start the season. http://www.newsvine.com/_news/2009/04/11/nationals-8-5?category=sports";



</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" name="newsHeadlines" method="get">
</form>

<table style="border: 0; width: 100%">
<tr valign="top">
<td>
<select name="headline" multiple="multiple"
 style="height: 93px">
<option onclick="document.newsHeadlines.news.value=newItem1">Investigation of building standards in quake zone</option>

<option onclick="document.newsHeadlines.news.value=newsItem2">Obama sees signs of economic progress</option>

<option onclick="document.newsHeadlines.news.value=newsItem3">Apple App Downloads Approach 1 Billion</option>

<option onclick="document.newsHeadlines.news.value=newsItem4">Jones, Braves beat winless Nationals 8-5</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<textarea id="news" name="news" cols="50" rows="10" 
 style="background-color: transparent"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

can someone help me fix the problem everytime i click on "Investigation of building standards in quake zone" nothing shows in the textarea i created.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be too late for your assignment, I thought I should point out some errors in the code and try to implement what you are intending to, i.e. displaying different newsItems upon clicking corresponding select option.

1. `document.getElementById( 'news' ).innerHTML='newsItem1';` 

   should be written after the textbox tag with id 'news' is declared, or else will give null value.
2. In `<option onclick="document.newsHeadlines.news.value=newItem1>`,

   there's a typo (`newItem1` should be `newsItem1`) and the onclick attribute value is not correct. To correctly select the textbox and display intended text in it, you should use the following:
    `onclick="document.getElementById('name').value=newsItem1"`.
    Use similar values for rest of the options.